# Unable to locate element in iFrame

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to get an xpath for a certain button/Frame. I am able to locate the element using the xpath but while running automation I am getting element not found exception. I tried to switch to the particular frame and then finding the button but it did'nt work.  Attaching the link for the page and Image. 
Link : https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today/New-Delhi,Delhi,India/we-city-28.608,77,201?iso=IN
[image]

Here is the code I tried.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(cdriver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='foot']//following::iframe[@style='width:9.7rem;']")));
System.out.println("Ive waited for the frame to load");
int size = cdriver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
System.out.println(size);

/*for(int i=0; i<=size; i++){
cdriver.switchTo().frame(i);
System.out.println("Switched to frame "+i);
int total=  cdriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='u_0_0']/div/button/span")).size();
System.out.println(total);
cdriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}*/

cdriver.switchTo().frame(2);
System.out.println("Switched to frame");

cdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u_0_0']/div/button/span")).click();
```

Getting the number of frames present and then checking in each for the element but its not able to switch to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

To access the desired elements as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()`.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today/New-Delhi,Delhi,India/we-city-28.608,77,201?iso=IN")
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src^='//www.facebook.com/plugins/like']")));
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today/New-Delhi,Delhi,India/we-city-28.608,77,201?iso=IN")
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@src, '//www.facebook.com/plugins/like')]")));
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: He is using Java, not Python.

Comment: @Guy Good catch :)

Answer (score 0):

When you used `switchTo().frame(2)` you actually switched to the third `<iframe>`. You can use `switchTo().frame(1)`, but better choice will be to use unique identifier rather than index

```
WebElement iframe = cdriver.findElement(By.csSelector("#fbcount > iframe"));
cdriver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

To wait for a frame to load use `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`, not `elementToBeClickable`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.csSelector("#fbcount > iframe")));
System.out.println("Switched to frame");
```